# Переопределение аргумента списка внутри функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list, переменные

Пишу функцию, которая продвигает элементы по списку, как по кругу (последний элемент становится первым, все остальные двигаются вперёд).

```
def spinForward(array):
    N = len(array);
    newArray = [];
    newArray.append(array[N-1]);
    newArray.extend(array);
    newArray.pop();
    array = newArray[:];
```

На следующий вызов:

```
a = ["how", "are", "you", "?"]
spinForward(a);
print(a);
```

Ожидаю получить:

```
['?', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Однако этого не происходит, исходный список при этом нисколько не меняется.

Конструкция работает в таком случае:

```
def spinForward(array):
    N = len(array);
    newArray = [];
    newArray.append(array[N-1]);
    newArray.extend(array);
    newArray.pop();
    while array:
        array.pop();
    array.extend(newArray);
```

Читал на Стеке про глобальные переменные, но если помечать `array` оператором `global`, то вылетает ошибка на то, что `array` - одновременно и входная, и глобальная переменная, а даже если это как-то исправить (хотя как?), придется входной список перед вызовом именовать `array`, что, мне кажется, уж точно неверно.

**Есть ли более гибкий вариант переопределения входного параметра или же мой рабочий вариант реализован хорошо?**

Comment: Про retrun  вам написали, а вообще то вся ваша функция `return [array[-1]] + array[:-1]`

Comment: `while array:
        array.pop();
    array.extend(newArray);` вот это все можно `array[:] = newArray`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы по месту изменить список, можно [срез](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4279) использовать:

```
def spin_forward(array):
    array[:] = array[-1:] + array[:-1]
```

Или можно вернуть новое значение, не трогая входной список:

```
def spinned_forward(array):
    return array[-1:] + array[:-1]
```

Разница такая же как между `lst.sort()`, который сортирует список по месту (и возвращает `None`) и `sorted(lst)`, который оставляет `lst` без изменений и возвращает новый отсортированный список ([Command-query separation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS)).

Чтобы эффективно перемещать (вращать) элементы, [можно `collections.deque` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate):

```
>>> import collections
>>> q = collections.deque(["how", "are", "you", "?"])
>>> q
deque(['how', 'are', 'you', '?'])
>>> q.rotate(1)
>>> q
deque(['?', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
```

`.rotate(1)` это `O(1)` операция (время выполнения не зависит от размера ввода), в то время как реализации `spin_forward(array)` выше это `O(n)` операция (время выполнения растёт с размером ввода — чем больше ввод, тем дольше).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше вернуть значение, чем глобальную переменную использовать:

```
def spin_forward(array):
    N = len(array)
    new_array = []
    new_array.append(array[N-1])
    new_array.extend(array)
    new_array.pop()

    return new_array

a = ["how", "are", "you", "?"]
a = spin_forward(a)
print(a)  # ['?', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```